# Laravel/Eloquent advises to override a trait property?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, traits, laravel-5.4

I'm using Eloquent models within Laravel 5.4
In the documentation, I see:

> You may also use the create method to save a new model in a single
>   line. The inserted model instance will be returned to you from the
>   method. However, before doing so, you will need to specify either a
>   fillable or guarded attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models
>   protect against mass-assignment by default.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

However, the $fillable property is already defined in a trait used by all models:

```
trait GuardsAttributes
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [];

...
```

The PHP documentation is clear about Traits properties:

> If a trait defines a property then a class can not define a property
>   with the same name, otherwise an error is issued. It is an E_STRICT if
>   the class definition is compatible (same visibility and initial value)
>   or fatal error otherwise.

Is the Laravel documentation wrong about the adivsed implementation?

Comment: Neither are wrong. You have class `A` and you use a trait inside that class. Trait = language assisted copy paste. Class `A` can't contain `protected $fillable` - and it doesn't, because your class `A` is `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`. So far so good - but now you are extending the `Model` and you can override the `protected $fillable` property. Inheritance rules allow for this. Your question is valid, but so are both excerpts from documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot override trait properties in the same class as the PHP documentation suggests.

Laravel, however, is asking you to override this in a child class (your model class which extends the Eloquent model class and the trait is included in the Eloquent model class, not your model class). This is a perfectly valid thing to do!